# Qt: Can you use QStringList as a function parameter when connecting an action using QSignalMapper?

Tags: qt

I was wondering if that was possible. To be more explicit, I already have connected actions using QSignalMapper, but the slot function's parameter was a QString, which was fine since there is a QSignalMapper signal that has a QString parameter and it doesn't give any problem. But is there a way to use a QStringList?

The idea would be like this:

```
connect(action, SIGNAL(triggered(bool)), mapper, SLOT(map()));
connect(mapper, SIGNAL(mapped(QString)), this,  SLOT(myFunc(QString)));
```

This one works, and I'd like to know if there is a way to do it using a QStringList instead of QString?

Comment: it seems the developers of Qt only implemented int, QString, QObject and QWidget, so the answer would be no. Maybe you can use a comma-separated-valuelist as solution?

Comment: Well, I just wanted to know if maybe someone knew some kind of way, but it's alright if it's not possible, I'll find some workaround for my problem.

Comment: Do you really *need* a `QSignalMapper`?  With the new signal/slot syntax it's generally cleaner to use `lambda`s with appropriate capture lists instead.  Indeed, `QSignalMapper` appears to be labelled [obsolete](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsignalmapper.html).

Comment: Indeed I noticed that QSignalMapper became deprecated. In fact, I kind of changed my mind and use lambda expressions instead and change where I used QSignalMapper.